# Bet out of turn

Tags: betting-position

If a player bets out of turn may the player that got bypassed by this action check then subsequently raise once action is back to that player?

Answer (score 4):

As always, rules may vary by cardroom, but generally yes. The common rule is that an out-of-turn action is binding if the intervening action does not change (whether that action is a check or call). If an intervening player raises, then the out-of-turn player is off the hook and may take any action.

So in your scenario, player 1 checks, player 2 is silent while player 3 bets out of turn, player 2 can either object that it is his turn and make an action of his own, or he can simply check, in which case player 3's bet stands, and players 1 and 2 are perfectly entitled to raise when the action gets back to them.